# Default shipped file

Tags: 16.04, files, default

I don't know if this question is on topic. I don't see any restrictions [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask).

---

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus) comes with:

```
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/Soul.ogg
```

md5sum: `f874ae21625f7e1f090cdf1e93b1254d`

**Where can I find more information about this file?**
(is this part of a longer piece? which piece? who composed it?)

I don't know the license of this file so I have not uploaded it.

Comment: Maybe shazam can recognize the song for you?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd assume you'd have to look back to find the version of Ubuntu where it was introduced, where I'd expect to find small footnotes about the files origins. The license will be CC (creative commons), or GPL2 or later..., but `apt-file find /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/Soul.ogg` tells me its from the `ubuntu-touch-sounds` package, so maybe its different, being from  Canonical's phone project possibly...  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/ubuntu-touch-sounds/filelist)